# Parallelizing a call in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
List<ObjectA> allObjects = (List<ObjectA>) objArepository.findAll();

for (ObjectA objA : allObjects) {
        String location = objA.getUrl();

        Client client = utils.createClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(location).path("/testUrl/" + someString); 
        Invocation.Builder requestBuilder = webTarget.request();
        Response response;
        try {
            response = request.invoke();
            }
        }
```

instead of the for loop which sends those calls serially, I would like to send those calls all parallely, the problem is for that I didn't find any examples and I am missing an idea how to do that in java

Comment: Just a suggestion -- Apache Spark is a great open source tool for parallel computing. It'd be worth your time to look into, but that's up to you.

Comment: Multithreading would be the simple answer here. But that will depends on the number of request, if there is no limit, you should use a pool thread to limit the number of request, or you would overload the server receiving the request. Note that I would prefer a callback method instead of having a multithreading system, but this would need more work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

The `executorService.invokeAll` can execute a list of tasks in parallel and wait them to complete.

```
ExecutorService executor = getExecutorService();
List<Request> requests = getRequests();
List<Callable> tasks = requests.stream()
    .map(r -> new Processor(r))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

executor.invokeAll(tasks);
```

If you need asynchronous calls, use `executorService.submit` or `executorService.execute`

## Update

According to the comment, I add a few more words about the code above.

`getExecutorServices()` returns a executorService created in other places, maybe a singleton, since the creation of an executorService is quite expensive.

`getRequests()` returns a list of requests, `Request` can be anything you want to process, such as `ObjectA` in the question.

`executorService.invokeAll` accepts a list of [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), so you have to encapsulate your requests in callables. `Processor` is a callable to process `Request`.

Actually, I think the code is quite descriptive and an ordinary Java programmer can understand it.

Comment: Your answer is difficult to understand, as it has references to unknown code.  What does `getExecutorService()` do to obtain an ExecutorService?  What is a `Request` and what is `getRequests()`?  What is a `Processor`?

Comment: I will try that out tomorrow and when it works I'll give you the right answer :) thanks so far for the help